# Will using "Erase all contents and settings" restore to factory OS?

Tags: ios, iphone, reset

I just upgraded my iPhone 5 to iOS 8, but I want to restore it to iOS 7 for testing purposes. Is it the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from beta versions of iOS, it appears to be no longer possible to install any version of iOS except the most recent release. "Erase all content and settings" will clean all of your content out, but leave the OS intact. The older iOS version isn't there, and you wouldn't be allowed to install it if you had a copy.

And even if you try to install an older iOS version with Xcode, Apple's servers will refuse to authorize any version but the most recent.

Looks like you're stuck this way until people stop trying to jailbreak...

Comment: Well that sucks. Thanks Justin!